# How to use aws-sdk for creating ec2 instance on a vpc and subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

Is my code right? how to configure a VPC  and subnet?

```
    
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
   
    AWS.config.update({
      region: 'us-east-1',
      accessKeyId: 'qwertyuio',
      secretAccessKey: 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa,',
    });
    
    var ec2 = new AWS.EC2({ apiVersion: '2016-11-15' });
    var instanceParams = {
      ImageId: 'ami-0022f774911c1d690',
      InstanceType: 't2.micro',
      KeyName: 'ec2_sampleKey1',
      MinCount: 1,
      MaxCount: 1,
    };

    var instancePromise = new AWS.EC2({ apiVersion: '2016-11-15' })
      .runInstances(instanceParams)
      .promise();
    
    instancePromise
      .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        var instanceId = data.Instances[0].InstanceId;
        console.log('Created instance', instanceId);
        tagParams = {
          Resources: [instanceId],
          Tags: [
            {
              Key: 'sampleEC2',
              Value: 'myEC2SampleTag',
            },
          ],
        };
  
        var tagPromise = new AWS.EC2({ apiVersion: '2016-11-15' })
          .createTags(tagParams)
          .promise();
        tagPromise
          .then(function (data) {
            console.log('Instance tagged');
          })
          .catch(function (err) {
            console.error(err, err.stack);
          });
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.error(err, err.stack);
      });
```

This code is exactly what is given in the documentation of aws-sdk for nodejs. Please tell me how to configure VPC and subnet on this code.
Is it in config params or update method??

Answer (score 0):

Add `SubnetId` to the `instanceParams` when calling [runInstances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#runInstances-property).

You don't need to indicate the VPC because it's implicitly derived from the subnet ID.